# C-programming code (help)

Tags: c, for-loop

This program prints the elements of an array wherein the elements are provided by the user. The maximum size of the array is: 10*40 i.e 10 rows and 40 columns. Below is a sample of the provided input and the corresponding expected output. The actual output doesn't seem to match the expected output. What could be the issue?

Sample run of the program:

Input:
Number of rows:3
Number of columns: 7

Elements of the array:

8 8 3 5 1 7 0

9 2 6 9 7 4 0

5 3 9 3 7 6 6

Expected Output:

8 8 3 5 1 7 0

9 2 6 9 7 4 0

5 3 9 3 7 6 6

Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define R 10
#define C 40
int main(void)
{  
   int rc[R][C];
   int i=0; int j=0;
   int r , c;
   scanf("%d %d",&r,&c);

   for(i=0;i<r;i++)
   {

      for(j=0;j<c;j++)
      {          
        scanf("%d",&rc[i][j]);      
        if(i==r-1&&i==c-1)
           goto a;
     }

   }

 a:
   for(i=0;i<r;i++)
   {

      for(j=0;j<c;j++)
      {
         printf("%d ",rc[i][j]);      
      }
   printf("\n");
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: Also format the code correctly, you've messed it up a little bit there...

Comment: Your input seems to match with output. What exactly is the issue? Also this `if(i==r-1&&i==c-1)` check and use of `goto` seem needless here. The loop runs for `r x c` times. No need for another jump there.

Comment: That "goto" looks incorrect, and also unnecessary.

Comment: The `if (...) goto a;` is particularly alarming, first of all for using `goto` in this instance, secondly for using the label `a`, and lastly, because the loop will already exit when that condition is true (assuming you meant `if (i == r - 1 && j == c - 1)`).

Comment: Homework question?

First, never use `scanf()` as you run the risk of buffer overflow. Use `fgets()` instead. 

Second, using jumps is absolutely unnecessary in such a simple program, and actually does nothing in your case. `if(i==r-1&&i==c-1)` will happen anyway as the for loop will exit if this is the case. Remove that line and the `a:`.

Apart from that the code seems ok and should be fine.

Comment: @jonogilmour: `scanf()` won't cause a buffer overflow unless you are using it to scan for strings, which OP is not.

Comment: But educating the OP (obviously a new programmer) on the risks of `scanf()` is worthwhile in my mind (even if it isn't absolutely necessary in this program specifically).

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if(i==r-1&&i==c-1)
```

Should be

```
if(i==r-1&&j==c-1)
```

Better yet, you can probably remove that, the goto and the label altogether. Let the for loops do the work for you of preventing it from going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {  

    int row , column;
    int rowCount, columnCount;


    printf("Please enter row length:\n>");
    scanf("%d", &row);

    printf("\nPlease enter column length:\n>");
    scanf("%d", &column);

    int numbers[row][column];

    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < row; rowCount++) {

        for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < column; columnCount++) {

            printf("Please enter the %d. number for row %d:\n>", columnCount+1, rowCount+1);
            scanf(" %d", &numbers[rowCount][columnCount]);      
        }

    }


    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < row; rowCount++) {

        for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < column; columnCount++)
            printf("%d ", numbers[rowCount][columnCount]);      

        printf("\n");
    }


   return 0;
}
```

BTW: don't use `goto`! So bad pratice!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the if condition at all, the for loops take care of it. The moment i ==r the input for loops are exited and the loops pertaining to print get executed. So the below code should be good:

```
for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<c;j++)          
    scanf("%d",&rc[i][j]);      
}


for(i=0;i<r;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<c;j++)
  {
     printf("%d",rc[i][j]);      
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
```